# Facebook Graph Api & Android - SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to access a graph api URL with android.

```
public static String getResponseFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xml;
    }
```

I call this method for a graph api url such as

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{ID}/feed?fields=message,object_id&filter=app_2305272732&access_token=token
```

And I get

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
04-04 15:54:59.077    1936-1991/com.fainosag.virginradiolebanon W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:146)
04-04 15:54:59.081    1936-1991/W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
04-04 15:54:59.081    1936-1991/W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:388)
04-04 15:54:59.081    1936-1991/W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.updateSecureConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:231)
04-04 15:54:59.089    1936-1991/  W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.layerProtocol(AbstractPoolEntry.java:302)
04-04 15:54:59.089    1936-1991/ n W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.layerProtocol(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:146)
04-04 15:54:59.089    1936-1991/ W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:654)
04-04 15:54:59.089    1936-1991/ W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:370)
04-04 15:54:59.089    1936-1991/ W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-04 15:54:59.089    1936-1991/ W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-04 15:54:59.089    1936-1991/ W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-04 15:54:59.089    1936-1991/  W/System.err﹕ at com.fainosag.......http.HttpHelper.getResponseFromUrl(HttpHelper.java:30)
```

Everything works in browser.

Comment: What kind of connection are you on? I have seen this issue before when the device did not have an active connection so there could be an issue with that. Do other calls to Facebook work properly on your Android device?

Comment: No. I;m getting that error on both emulator and device